# What happens when you "Require" a Trait in php?

Tags: php, include, require, traits

Will it work if I attempt to require or include a trait in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Require or Include are simply ways of merging source files together in php.  So yes, you can include or require a file that includes one or more trait definitions.

Answer (score 1):

**include show warning error attempt to load the specified file but will allow the script to continue if not successfully loaded**

more detail  http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php

**Require  show fatal error to occur if the specified file is not successfully loaded and stop the script execution.**

more detail http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php